# Keycloak social login rest api

Tags: java, rest, authentication, keycloak

I have enabled google social login for my keycloak instance, but I need to use it as a rest service.

Is there endpoint that can be used to do this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56776381/keycloak-identity-broker-api

Answer (score 1):

There is no Google authentication API in the Keycloak but you can solve it with [Token Exchanging](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/14.0/securing_apps/#_token-exchange).

1. You need first authenticate with [Google API](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server) and get an external
   token,
2. [External Token to Internal Token Exchange.](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/14.0/securing_apps/#external-token-to-internal-token-exchange)