# Keycloak Identity Broker API

Tags: java, spring, keycloak

So i have a client which consumes an api. The API is secured with keycloak.
Users signs in normally, but i want to allow users to sign in user without having to go keycloak's login page with their social media accounts like facebook or google.
I need a rest API with an implementation of how to get a url generated so when user click on this url in a button, it will take the user to the respective social login page to login while keycloak still serves as the broker.

Below is my implementation, it generates a url alright but does not take the user to google page to login

This is a rest Controller

```
    @Secured("permitAll")
    @GetMapping(path = "/generator")
    public String brokerGenerator(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) throws ServletException {
        String provider = "google";
        String authServerRootUrl = "http://localhost:8080/";
        String realm = "realmName";
        String clientId = "clientName";
        String nonce = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        MessageDigest md = null;

        try {
            md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        String input = nonce + clientId + provider;
        byte[] check = md.digest(input.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        String hash = Base64Url.encode(check);
        httpServletRequest.getSession().setAttribute("hash", hash);

        String redirectUri = "http://localhost:4200/dashboard"; 

        return KeycloakUriBuilder.fromUri(authServerRootUrl)
                .path("auth/realms/realmName/google/link")
                .queryParam("nonce", nonce)
                .queryParam("hash", hash)
                .queryParam("client_id", clientId)
                .queryParam("redirect_uri", redirectUri).build(realm, provider).toString();

    }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Keycloak supports this out of the box. See https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/index.html#_client_suggested_idp

> OIDC applications can bypass the Keycloak login page by specifying a hint on which identity provider they want to use.
>
> This is done by setting the kc_idp_hint query parameter in the Authorization Code Flow authorization endpoint.

**UPDATE**

In your case you should use normal Keycloak Auth Code Flow endpoint and in addition to the basic query params provide `kc_idp_hint` param. This way the user is redirected to Keycloak login page first then Keycloak redirects him to the chosen identity provider login page (google in your case).

Here is an example redirect URL:

```
https://keycloak-domain/realms/REALM_NAME/protocol/openid-connect/auth?client_id=CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI&state=STATE&response_type=code&scope=openid&nonce=NONCE&kc_idp_hint=google
```

Edit your code according this example:

```
return KeycloakUriBuilder.fromUri(authServerRootUrl)
    .path("realms/realmName/protocol/openid-connect/auth") // Url changed
    .queryParam("response_type", "code") // Autherization Code Flow
    .queryParam("scope", "openid") // Add additional scopes if needed
    .queryParam("kc_idp_hint", "google") // This should match IDP name registered in Keycloak
    .queryParam("nonce", nonce)
    .queryParam("hash", hash)
    .queryParam("client_id", clientId)
    .queryParam("redirect_uri", redirectUri).build(realm, provider).toString();
```

You can manually initiate Keycloak redirection for test. Start normal login flow and when you redirected to Keycloak login page do not enter credentials, instead add `kc_idp_hint=google` to the URL and hit ENTER. Then you will be redirected right to Google login page.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little further, please.

Comment: Ok, that is great, but, i get the uri alright, i  copy it to the browser and punched enter/return key. Instead of taking me to the google login page, takes me to the redirect url rathe. I don't know if you understand me.

Comment: After you added `&kc_idp_hint=google` and pressed ENTER you get redirected back to redirect URL? This happens if there is no IDP with given name configured in selected realm.

Comment: Yes, it generates a url like https://keycloak-domain/realms/REALM_NAME/protocol/openid-connect/auth?client_id=CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI&state=STATE&response_type=code&scope=openid&nonce=NONCE&kc_idp_hint=google
alright, but it takes me to the redirect url used in my queryParam redirect uri

Comment: Clear cookies or better try in incognito mode. Your browser cached Google/Keycloak auth data in previous login attempts.

Comment: did that. This is the uri i get

Comment: http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/RealmName/broker/google/link?response_type=code&scope=openid+profile+email&kc_idp_hint=google&nonce=58d2ba20-8ac4-45d2-a82b-2df8800a7e16&hash=btA7YxWCY_e8AKQtKYWltc1Dbmn-lSfPnTYSb1e3wV0&client_id=googleId&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4200%2Fdashboard

Comment: when i punch enter, then change to http://localhost:4200/dashboard?link_error=not_logged_in&nonce=6a6c6255-13c7-4a1b-bf6e-ceb9f6618952

Comment: will still be trying my way around it though, will update of any progress

Comment: Its is woring now....I changes the nonce to state ```.queryParam("state", nonce)```

Comment: is there a way to allow user to unlink after or there isn't?

Comment: @yormen please ask this in a separate question, not in a comment.

Comment: I have, kindly check out this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57877569/unlinking-social-provider-from-user-keycloak

Comment: have u seen it?

Comment: Hi @yormen didn't have time to check it. I left a comment there.

Comment: @VadimAshikhman Could you please answer on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69696020/keycloak-social-login-rest-api-redirected-you-too-many-times

Comment: first link is broken, the new one is this. https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/index.html#_client_suggested_idp

Comment: @Claudio Thanks. I'v corrected the link.