# Unlinking social provider from user keycloak

Tags: spring, keycloak

I have an application that makes use of the use of account linking with keycloak and spring.
The account linking works alright but the issue is account unlinking

Kindly click here to check out the account linking [Keycloak Identity Broker API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56776381/keycloak-identity-broker-api)

Now i want to create similar one for account UNLINKING.

I couldn't get around it

Comment: Do you want to generate a link to Keycloak Server and after clicking on this link account will be unlinked from specified external identity provider?

Comment: @VadimAshikhman Yes

Comment: @ Vadim Ashikhman Can you please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just had the same issue, and what I found out is that you can use the admin api to unlink users from social IdPs.

https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/12.0/rest-api/index.html#_users_resource

Specifically here:

[image: admin api unlink]